# Equivalent of Universal wrap panel in iOS

Tags: ios, user-interface, cocoa-touch

C# has provided a Universal Wrap Panel. Using this, we can place the elements according to their content size. Is there any equivalent concept in iOS?

Comment: Yes - a `UICollectionView`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview

Comment: BTW: Neither C# has a wrap panel nor swift/Objective-C has a collection view.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Quite true - but since the OP used the iOS tag it seemed appropriate to assume the question was about iOS.

Comment: @bobnoble Th commentary wasn't about yours, but about the Q itself.

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionView` is actually the correct way to go. You can calculate the size you needed for the content, and then adjust the cell of within the collection view by this delegate method

```
extension YourViewController : NSCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: NSCollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSSize {

        return NSSize(width: calculatedWidth, height: CalculatedHeight)
    }
}
```